# how to change the remaining annual leave column value to default at the beginning of each year?

Tags: sql, function, mariadb

| Id | Name | residual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ruri | 12 |
| 2 | Trala | 10 |
| 3 | Suki | 4 |

*This is a table of the remaining annual leave of employees*.

in this table every employee takes leave, then the remaining column of annual leave will *automatically decrease* according to the annual leave taken.

The weakness of this table is that at the beginning of each year, the remaining annual leave column must be *updated manually to return the default value* of 12.

is there a way in the MariaDB database to *automatically return the default values* ​​at the beginning of each year? and how?

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to run a job on Dec 31 or Jan 1st (or whenever your year starts) doing an update:

```
update leave_table
    set residual = 12;
```

However, I don't really recommend that.  Instead, fix your application so the table has an additional column with the year being processed.  Then you can *insert* new rows for a given year *any any time*.

In addition, this would make it simpler to give annual leave to people who start in the middle of the year and to provide different amounts of leave to different employees.

I also wouldn't recommend changing the value in the table.  Instead, keep track of how much leave someone has taken and subtract that from a value stored for each employee (or for each employee per year).

Answer (score 0):

you can execute Job Event to first day of a year that will set your required columns value to 12.

In this you can insert another column name YEAR to carry forward(if required) or start new for any new year with value 12.